# Target a Flash Param with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, attributes

Still dipping my toes into jQuery. I have this:

```
<span id="copyButton" class="copyButton">
<object id="copy_but" width="100%" height="30" align="middle" style="width:100%;height:30px;" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
<param value="http://cdn.domain.com/Graphics/images/share/copyButton.swf" name="movie">
<param value="Transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="text2copy=http://domain.us/1acSKSF" name="FlashVars">
<param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param value="false" name="allowFullScreen">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="#f7f7f7" name="bgcolor">
<object width="100%" height="30" style="width:100%;height:30px;" data="http://cdn.domain.com/Graphics/images/share/copyButton.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="http://cdn.domain.com/Graphics/images/share/copyButton.swf" name="movie">
<param value="Transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="text2copy=http://domain.us/1acSKSF" name="FlashVars">
<param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param value="false" name="allowFullScreen">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="#f7f7f7" name="bgcolor">
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
</object>
</object>
</span>
```

And I want to change the URL where it says "text2copy" in both areas. a couple of lines I've tried just to test reading the values are (always returns "undefined"):

```
$("#copy_but param[name='FlashVars']").attr("value")
$("param[value*='text2copy']").attr("value")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to work for your Flash movie though.

Comment: It's a Flash object, but not a movie, it's a Copy URL to Clipboard Flash Object.

Comment: I meant an SWF ;-). Does it update itself if you change the flashvars?

Comment: @putvande I think you're right. I've managed to get everything to edit and DISPLAY w/jQ fine in Chrome (Firefox seems to ignore it all *argh*), except when the actual Copy button is pressed, the original URL is the one copied to clipboard instead of the one shown in the source.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `#` for your id selector.

```
$("#copy_but param[name='FlashVars']").attr("value")
```

Comment: doh! you're right, lol. Unfortunately it still returns Undefined when the # is added.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein as the other comment said, not sure your approach is going to work, but in terms of debugging you should start inspecting the result of `$("#copy_but")` in the console.

Comment: Well, it seems that both of my original commands work in the console, (I got Undefined when trying to view them as an Alert), but I get errors when trying toactually change the value now. adding `.val("test")`, `.text("test")`, and `.replaceWith("test")` give errors.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein is your code within `$(document).ready(function(){/*Your code here*/})`.  That could be why you are `undefined`.